# Extracting product URLs from a search query on a website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

If I were for example looking to track the price changes of MIDI keyboards on https://www.gear4music.com/Studio-MIDI-Controllers. I would need to extract all the URLs of the products pictured from the search and then loop through the URLs of the products and extract price info for each product. I can obtain the price data of an individual product by hard coding the URL but I cannot find a way to automate getting the URLs of multiple products.

So far I have tried this,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.gear4music.com/Studio-MIDI- Controllers"

response = requests.get(url)

data = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

tags = soup.find_all('a')

for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href'))
```

This does produce a list of URLs but I cannot make out which ones relate specifically to the MIDI keyboards in that search query that I want to obtain the price product info of. Is there a better more specific way to obtain the URLs of the products only and not everything within the HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways how to obtain product links. One way could be select all `<a>` tags which have `data-g4m-inv=` attribute:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.gear4music.com/Studio-MIDI-Controllers"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select("a[data-g4m-inv]"):
    print("https://www.gear4music.com" + a["href"])
```

Prints:

```
https://www.gear4music.com/Recording-and-Computers/SubZero-MiniPad-MIDI-Controller/P6E
https://www.gear4music.com/Recording-and-Computers/SubZero-MiniControl-MIDI-Controller/P6D
https://www.gear4music.com/Keyboards-and-Pianos/SubZero-MiniKey-25-Key-MIDI-Controller/JMR
https://www.gear4music.com/Keyboards-and-Pianos/Nektar-SE25/2XWA
https://www.gear4music.com/Keyboards-and-Pianos/Korg-nanoKONTROL2-USB-MIDI-Controller-Black/G8L
https://www.gear4music.com/Recording-and-Computers/SubZero-ControlKey25-MIDI-Keyboard/221Y
https://www.gear4music.com/Keyboards-and-Pianos/SubZero-CommandKey25-Universal-MIDI-Controller/221X

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the chrome developer console and look at the div that corresponds to a product, from there, set a variable(lets say "product") equal to soup.find_all(that aforementioned div) and loop through these results to find  tags that are children of that element (or alternatively identify the title class and search that way).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).